# Query ManyToMany SpringBoot

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, many-to-many

I have the following modeling:

```
table hackathon
idEvent int pk ai
...


table team
idTeam int pk ai
...

table hackathon_has_team
hackathon_id int
team_id int
....
```

And I need to select all the teams that are in an event by event id and I'm breaking my head with it, can anyone help?

I'm trying to do this but it does not work:

```
@Query("SELECT t " 
    + "FROM Team t INNER JOIN hackathon_has_team " 
    + "ON hackathon_has_team.team_id = t.id " 
    + "WHERE hackathon_has_team.hackathon_id = :hackathon_id")
public Page<Team> getListAllTeamsByIdOfHackathon(@Param("hackathon_id ") Long id, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data and desired result would helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to provide more to get more, but depending on how you are obtaining the list of the teams, you could try:

```
select * from event_has_team
where (select team_id from table team)
```

This selects everything from the event_has_team table where the team_id is in the team table. you can also add a where clause for teams you've identified in that sub-select or nit he main select, depending on what you really need.

Comment: this is not the case